# Connect via Remmina to XRDP on Centos 7 returns blank black screen

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, centos

I have a fresh virtual machine with Centos 7, there was no DE (it's a machine in cloud system). So, I connect via ssh and installed group "GNOME Desktop", and then installed xrdp as here http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/install-xrdp-on-centos-7-rhel-7.html#axzz3bR4gAmRT

And when I connect with Remmina from my Debian it shows blank black screen.

Comment: Which version of Remmina are you using?

Comment: 0.9.99.1, but does it matter? Because I can connect to any windows VM, it seems like problem only on that CentOS

Comment: Yes, _the size matters_ :) Remmina 0.9.x development has stalled, try the `next` version from https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina

Comment: I do think, that something wrong on that machine. Because I tried also another program. So, I tried to run:
gnome-session
No protocol specified
(gnome-session-check-accelerated:3338): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
No protocol specified
(gnome-session-check-accelerated:3346): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 
** (process:3333): WARNING **: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
No protocol specified
** (gnome-session:3333): WARNING **: Could not open X display
** (gnome-session:3333): WARNING **: Cannot open display: